# Глючное вчера у дат

Tags: дефект, поддержка

Обратил внимание на использование системой "вчера" в [соседнем вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11565/178988) даже после обновления страницы.

На скриншоте подсвечено (в том же порядке):

```
вчера            2021-06-06 21:17:21Z
вчера            2021-06-06 21:17:58Z
9 секунд назад   2021-06-08 09:29:22Z
```

Вроде бы должно быть не "вчера", а "позавчера"?

[image: скриншот]

Comment: При переводе в московский часовой пояс получается 2021-06-07 00:17:21+03:00, так что, видимо, всё-таки вчера)

Comment: @andreymal, у меня ещё +1 к Москве. Но ведь дни на сайте считаются по гринвичу.

Comment: Блин, я этого даже не замечал раньше) Тогда предположу, что «вчера» закончится по истечении 48 часов, надо будет посмотреть в 2021-06-08 21:17:21Z изменится ли что-нибудь

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127668/339911

Comment: Таки да, 48 часов: [было](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n14dk.png), [стало](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOxNx.png)

Comment: @andreymal, т. е. перевод кривой и вместо "вчера" должно быть "позавчера"? Точнее не перевод, а вообще использование.